# Is it possible to encapsulate a GPUImage filter into a CIFilter?

Tags: iphone, ios, gpuimage, imagefilter, cifilter

I need to use a core image filter (`CIFilter`) in a certain method of iOS 7 (so I can't be more specific as it is under NDA). However, there is not a CIFilter which provides the filter I want to use. So I have search in the internet and I found the wonderful [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) library. It provides exactly the filters I need, and offers a great performance.

My problem is that the method for which I need the filter requires specifically a CIFilter. So my question is: is it possible to encapsulate a GPUImage filter into a CIFilter?

I have read the CIFilter docs and I saw this:

> You can subclass CIFilter in order to create:
>
> • A filter by chaining together two or more built-in Core Image filters (iOS and OS X)
>
> • A custom filter that uses an image processing kernel that you write (OS X only)

However, it doesn't forbid to subclass it for other uses, and the possibility to create custom filters (only in OS X) is using a core image kernel and not a external one.

**I would like to know if it is technically possible to encapsulate it, and whether it would be approved or not by Apple.** I know that is difficult to know if that will be approved.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the iOS 7 capability (on Apple's developer site) that you need the CIFilter for? I may be better able to give an answer based on that, and it shouldn't be an NDA violation if you link to the documentation behind their login-wall. In general, custom CIFilters are a no-go on iOS, but there might be another way to go about what you want.

Comment: It's a great idea, here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html Really, it'd be a different question, but I can't ask it... Thank you very much even if you don't give me a solution ;)

Comment: For a static filtered texture, you can use a GPUImageRawDataOutput to extract the output bytes and pass that in as texture data. For the others, I'd file a feature request to get them to expose the raw OpenGL ES resources so that you could hook something like GPUImage into it. The Scene Kit team did something like that in response to requests from developers. It's early enough that they might be able to work it in.

Comment: OK, thank you again for your answer. Unfortunately, I want to apply the filter in a non-static node. I'll try to file a feature request. By the way, if you write an answer saying that it's not possible I'll will accept it, to help future visitors.

Comment: @BradLarson I'm using GPUImage in my project to add realtime filters to camera input, and I would also like if I could integrate some of iOS 7 built in CIFilters as well (Eg:- CIPhotoEffectInstant,CIPhotoEffectFade etc). Maybe I can achieve the almost similar effect using GPUImage framework itself, But is there a way to directly use iOS CIFilters within GPUImage?

Comment: @whitewolf09 - The best way I could think of currently would be to exchange textures between GPUImage and an OpenGL ES context that Core Image could render to. Long-term, the best solution would probably be to implement those effects in GPUImage directly.

Comment: @BradLarson  I'll try the method you mentioned.Thank you very much for the quick reply and the amazing GPUImage library!

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx have you been able to wrap a CIFilter within a GPUImageFilter? I was looking for exactly the same.